# Access multiple router/modem with connected to single PC

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, automation, router, modem

I am setting up test automation setup for routers and modems provided by different third-party vendor. And, My goal to perform parallel execution on all the devices(routers) connected to single windows PC.

So, my question is, Is it possible to connect multiple routers to the single PC and should be able to access or login in all different routers GUI using same Ip address ex(192.168.1.254) with the same SSID and passphrase.

and if this is possible then If anyone having any idea how to automate this for example(any programming language like..python, power shell.etc)

Comment: Do you have any code example? please check [ask]

Comment: Unfortunately, not @dboy. Thats the reason I asked if there is any way because I am also in the process of doing parallel execution.